# Warning sdk angularfire on console log

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I have always had this warning and I cannot remove it in any way.
Use:
angular 11.0.1
@angular/fire 6.1.3
firebase 7.0.0 || 8.0.0

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import the individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the module builds, these are available in the following manner (replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

CommonJS Modules:

```
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/<PACKAGE>');
```

ES Modules:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/<PACKAGE>';
```

Typescript:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/<PACKAGE>';
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: You duplicated my error message, i use angular, i don't know where in libraries to change that value

Comment: Well, I answered this, because it is EXACTLY that. The very answer to your question.

Comment: Odds are you are importing firebase incorrectly somewhere in your codebase. AngularFire only pulls from `firebase/app`